# jquery numberformatter with new firefox 29

Tags: jquery, firefox, number-formatting

I'm using jquery-numberformatter 1.24 with hushtable 3.0 and jquery 1.7.1, to format number in my web app. I use only Firefox as client, after upgrading, today, at version 29 formatNumber function doesn't work anymore. I move back to version 28 and it works perfectly. I try last version of chrome and safari, as well,  and it doesn't work at all. So there is obviously something wrong in my code but I cannot see where is the problem.
This is the html:

```
<input type="number" id="quantity" onblur="formatValue(this);" value="0.0000000" required="" name="quantity">
```

Here the js function:

```
function formatValue(inputValue) {
    $(inputValue).parseNumber({format: "#,##0.0000000", locale: "us"});
    $(inputValue).formatNumber({format: "#,##0.0000000", locale: "us"});
}
```

I don't see any error logs in the js console. It's just return blank field instead of a correctly formatted number.
Any ideas?

thanks a lot

UPDATE:
I fix the issue basically removing the type="number" from the tag input. For me it's still a mistery why this happens, probably I have to investigate a bit more in the various JS that the page load, having time...

Answer (score 0):

you can use only javascript with :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function formatNum(val){
  val = Math.round(val*100)/100;
  val = (""+val).indexOf(".")>-1 ? val + "00" : val + ".00";
  var dec = val.indexOf(".");
  return dec == val.length-3 || dec == 0 ? val : val.substring(0,dec+3);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I see a lot of other implementation, but I'd like to stick to the original library.